# Intersect 2 list if first list contains part of another

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 list of string, `list A` and `list B`. `list A` is a list of strings containing paths, and the other contains strings of folder. Examples:

```
List<string> listA = new List<string>{ "c:\myPath\FolderA\blabla\", "c:\myPath\FolderB\blabla2\", "c:\myPath\FolderA\blabla3\" "c:\myPath\FolderC\blabla\"};
List<string> listB = new List<string> { "FolderA, FolderC"};
```

I want to have a method that compares the 2 list. If `listA` contains any of `listB` it is valid, else I don't want it. So based on this logic I'd have:

```
List<string> listReturn = new List<string>{ "c:\myPath\FolderA\blabla\", "c:\myPath\FolderA\blabla3\" "c:\myPath\FolderC\blabla\"};
```

So far all I've done is a method that iterates through the first list and does a `Contain` call on the string with a Linq `Any` call, like this:

```
private static List<string> FilterList(List<string> listA, List<string> listB)
{
    List<string> listReturn = new List<string>();

    foreach (string val in listA)
    {
        if (listB.Any(item => val.Contains(item)))
        {
            listReturn.Add(val);
        }
    }

    return listReturn;
}
```

It's not bad, but I want to use a Linq approach or a .NET approach if there's an Intersect method available for this. Thank you.

Comment: You can use LINQ `Where`, but not `Intersect` because the later require equality/hash comparison which is not applicable for partial matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Where()` against the `listA` to filter items in this list and `Exists()` on `listB` for the filter condition:

```
List<string> listA = new List<string> {@"c:\myPath\FolderA\blabla\", @"c:\myPath\FolderA\blabla2\", @"c:\myPath\Folder\blabla3\", @"c:\myPath\FolderC\blabla\"};
List<string> listB = new List<string> { "FolderA", "FolderC" };
var intersect = listA.Where(a => listB.Exists(b => a.Contains(b)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var result = listA.Where(i => listB.Any(y => i.Contains(y)).ToList();
```

Comment: Code works perfectly, I'll take Dmitry's answer simply because he was sooner but kudos for your code. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding :)